# How to get a specific sequence like this?

Tags: algorithm, math

There are 100 numbers:

1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,.. 50, 50.

How can I get a sequence which has one number between the two 1s, two numbers between the two 2s, three numbers between the two 3s,.. and fifty numbers between the two 50s using the hundred numbers?

Does anyone have a better idea than brute force? Or prove it there's no solution when n = 50.

Comment: Example for 8 numbers 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 The sequence is like 4,1,3,1,2,4,3,2.
Hope it helpful.

Comment: Are you sure, this is possible for all possible numbers? (It's not because it works with 4, it works for 50?)
Try to program the algorithm, in the way you made your first solution.

Comment: I think you should express better what you want (maybe using "two" instead of "2" when referring to counting and not a literal number in the sequence, or use quotes, whatever), now it's very weird to read.

Comment: Interesting question. Comment: there are no solutions for n = 1 or n = 2. There are exactly two solutions for n = 3: {{3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3}}. And exactly two for n = 4: {{4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4}}.

Comment: What led you to this problem?

Comment: @Andrew if there is one solution, there is at least another one that is symmetric (unless the solution was already a palindrome)

Comment: Just trolling, if I were to insert 0 or -ve for that part, I wouldn't be violating you contract. So for any sequence please feel free to take as many 0's as you need.

Comment: @VeeWee I'm not sure, I just try to find a thinking or an algorithm~ my first solution is just bruteforce, I think. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thanks for your advise, I've fixed them.

Comment: @Zoozy: Must the solution be presented with [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/index.html)? If not, remove that tag.

Comment: @Andrew Moylan

Yeah, I can find the solution for n = 3 and n = 4 with my pen and paper. For n = 1 and n = 2 there's obviously no solution. I wonder if there's a way just by drawing and hand-calculating to solve this n = 50, or prove it there's no solution mathematical strictly.

Comment: @questzen Make the sequence by using the given numbers, thanks for your attention.

Comment: @KennyTM Dont have to, and a Mathematica solution is also welcome, lol~

Comment: @fortran A solution can't be a palindrome, because the subsequence 1 _ 1 containing all ones has odd length.

Comment: @starblue I was suspecting that but didn't stop twice to think about it.

Comment: @Zoozy: As Andrew asked, What led you to this problem? What are the practical uses of such a sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only a solution to this problem for pairs of numbers from 1-n where n = 4m or n = 4m-1 for any positive integer m.

Update:

For any solution the odd number pairs must occupy two odd-numbered or two even-numbered positions.  The even number pairs must occupy one of each.  When there are an odd number of odd pairs (eg. 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 - 3 odd pairs) there is no solution.  There's no way to place the first number of each pair, without resulting in a clash when you try to place the second.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing

Another update:

My answer was basically from Knuth.  I've been thinking it through, though, and came up with the following on my own.

For any sequence {1 1 2 2 ... n n} there are, say, m odd pairs, n-m even pairs, and 2n positions in which to place them (i.e. n positions of each parity).

If you place the even pairs first then you use n-m even positions and n-m odd positions, thus you have m positions of each parity left in which to place the odd pairs.

The odd pairs must be placed in positions of the same parity.  If m is even there is no problem because half the pairs will will be placed in odd positions, and half in even positions.

If m is odd, however, you can only place m-1 of the odd pairs, at which point you'll have one odd pair left to place, and one position of each parity.  As the odd pair requires positions of the same parity there is no solution when m (the number of odd pairs) is odd.

Comment: Thanks very much, but how to prove it?

Answer (score 15):

#### The Problem: Langford Pairing

The problem is known as [Langford Pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langford_pairing). From Wikipedia:

> These sequences are named after C. Dudley Langford, who posed the problem of constructing them in 1958. As Knuth<sup>1</sup> describes, the problem of listing ***ALL*** Langford pairings for a given `N` can be solved as an instance of the [exact cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover_problem) (one of [Karp's 21 NP-complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems)), but for large `N` the number of solutions can be calculated more efficiently by algebraic methods.
>
> <sup>1</sup>: <sub>The Art of Computer Programming, IV, Fascicle 0: Introduction to Combinatorial Algorithms and Boolean Functions</sub>

It's worth noting that there is no solution for `N = 50`. Solutions only exist for `N = 4k` or `N = 4k - 1`. This is proven in a paper by Roy A. Davies (*On Langford's Problem II*, Math. Gaz. 43, 253-255, 1959), which also gives the pattern to construct a single solution for any feasible `N`.

#### Related links

- [John Miller's page on Langford's Problem](http://legacy.lclark.edu/%7Emiller/langford.html)

  - [A Perl program based on Roy A. Davies' pattern](http://legacy.lclark.edu/%7Emiller/langford/ROD.pl)
  - [Dave Moore's pattern](http://legacy.lclark.edu/%7Emiller/langford/dave-moore.html)
- [mathworld.wolfram - Langford's Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LangfordsProblem.html)
- [A CSP model for Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://www.amsterdamoptimization.com/msf.html)

---

#### Brute force in Java

Here are some solutions that my quick and dirty brute force program was able to find for `N < 100`. Nearly all of these were found in under a second.

```
 3 [3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
 4 [4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2]
 7 [7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 1]
 8 [8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1]
11 [11, 6, 10, 2, 9, 3, 2, 8, 6, 3, 7, 5, 11, 10, 9, 4, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 1]
12 [12, 10, 11, 6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 4, 6, 5, 10, 12, 11, 7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]
15 [15, 13, 14, 8, 5, 12, 7, 11, 4, 10, 5, 9, 8, 4, 7, 13, 15, 14, 12, 11, 10, 9, 6, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 6]
16 [16, 14, 15, 9, 7, 13, 3, 12, 6, 11, 3, 10, 7, 9, 8, 6, 14, 16, 15, 13, 12, 11, 10, 8, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4]
19 [19, 17, 18, 14, 8, 16, 9, 15, 6, 1, 13, 1, 12, 8, 11, 6, 9, 10, 14, 17, 19, 18, 16, 15, 13, 12, 11, 7, 10, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 7, 5, 4]
20 [20, 18, 19, 15, 11, 17, 10, 16, 9, 5, 14, 1, 13, 1, 12, 5, 11, 10, 9, 15, 18, 20, 19, 17, 16, 14, 13, 12, 8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 6]
23 [23, 21, 22, 18, 16, 20, 12, 19, 11, 8, 17, 4, 1, 15, 1, 14, 4, 13, 8, 12, 11, 16, 18, 21, 23, 22, 20, 19, 17, 15, 14, 13, 10, 7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 7, 5, 10, 9, 6]
24 [24, 22, 23, 19, 17, 21, 13, 20, 10, 8, 18, 4, 1, 16, 1, 15, 4, 14, 8, 10, 13, 12, 17, 19, 22, 24, 23, 21, 20, 18, 16, 15, 14, 11, 12, 7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 7, 5, 11, 9, 6]
27 [27, 25, 26, 22, 20, 24, 17, 23, 12, 13, 21, 7, 4, 19, 1, 18, 1, 4, 16, 7, 15, 12, 14, 13, 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 26, 24, 23, 21, 19, 18, 16, 15, 14, 11, 9, 10, 5, 2, 8, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 9, 11, 10, 8, 6]
28 [28, 26, 27, 23, 21, 25, 18, 24, 15, 13, 22, 10, 6, 20, 1, 19, 1, 3, 17, 6, 16, 3, 10, 13, 15, 18, 21, 23, 26, 28, 27, 25, 24, 22, 20, 19, 17, 16, 14, 12, 9, 7, 11, 4, 2, 5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 9, 5, 12, 14, 11, 8]
31 [31, 29, 30, 26, 24, 28, 21, 27, 18, 16, 25, 13, 11, 23, 6, 22, 5, 1, 20, 1, 19, 6, 5, 17, 11, 13, 16, 18, 21, 24, 26, 29, 31, 30, 28, 27, 25, 23, 22, 20, 19, 17, 15, 12, 14, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 9, 12, 10, 15, 14, 8, 7]
32 [32, 30, 31, 27, 25, 29, 22, 28, 19, 17, 26, 13, 11, 24, 6, 23, 5, 1, 21, 1, 20, 6, 5, 18, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 22, 25, 27, 30, 32, 31, 29, 28, 26, 24, 23, 21, 20, 18, 16, 15, 12, 14, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 9, 12, 10, 15, 14, 8, 7]
35 [35, 33, 34, 30, 28, 32, 25, 31, 22, 20, 29, 17, 14, 27, 10, 26, 5, 6, 24, 1, 23, 1, 5, 21, 6, 10, 19, 14, 18, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 35, 34, 32, 31, 29, 27, 26, 24, 23, 21, 19, 18, 16, 13, 15, 12, 9, 4, 2, 11, 3, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7, 9, 13, 12, 16, 15, 11, 8, 7]
36 [36, 34, 35, 31, 29, 33, 26, 32, 23, 21, 30, 17, 14, 28, 10, 27, 5, 6, 25, 1, 24, 1, 5, 22, 6, 10, 20, 14, 19, 17, 18, 21, 23, 26, 29, 31, 34, 36, 35, 33, 32, 30, 28, 27, 25, 24, 22, 20, 19, 18, 16, 13, 15, 12, 9, 4, 2, 11, 3, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7, 9, 13, 12, 16, 15, 11, 8, 7]
40 [40, 38, 39, 35, 33, 37, 30, 36, 27, 25, 34, 22, 20, 32, 17, 31, 13, 11, 29, 7, 28, 3, 1, 26, 1, 3, 24, 7, 23, 11, 13, 21, 17, 20, 22, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 38, 40, 39, 37, 36, 34, 32, 31, 29, 28, 26, 24, 23, 21, 19, 16, 18, 15, 12, 4, 6, 14, 2, 5, 4, 2, 10, 6, 9, 5, 8, 12, 16, 15, 19, 18, 14, 10, 9, 8]
43 [43, 41, 42, 38, 36, 40, 33, 39, 30, 28, 37, 25, 23, 35, 20, 34, 16, 14, 32, 5, 31, 8, 6, 29, 2, 5, 27, 2, 26, 6, 8, 24, 14, 16, 22, 20, 23, 25, 28, 30, 33, 36, 38, 41, 43, 42, 40, 39, 37, 35, 34, 32, 31, 29, 27, 26, 24, 22, 21, 19, 17, 15, 18, 12, 7, 1, 3, 1, 13, 4, 3, 11, 7, 10, 4, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, 21, 18, 13, 11, 10, 9]
44 [44, 42, 43, 39, 37, 41, 34, 40, 31, 29, 38, 26, 24, 36, 20, 35, 16, 14, 33, 5, 32, 8, 6, 30, 2, 5, 28, 2, 27, 6, 8, 25, 14, 16, 23, 20, 22, 24, 26, 29, 31, 34, 37, 39, 42, 44, 43, 41, 40, 38, 36, 35, 33, 32, 30, 28, 27, 25, 23, 22, 21, 19, 17, 15, 18, 12, 7, 1, 3, 1, 13, 4, 3, 11, 7, 10, 4, 9, 12, 15, 17, 19, 21, 18, 13, 11, 10, 9]
52 [52, 50, 51, 47, 45, 49, 42, 48, 39, 37, 46, 34, 32, 44, 29, 43, 26, 24, 41, 20, 40, 16, 14, 38, 7, 9, 36, 2, 35, 3, 2, 33, 7, 3, 31, 9, 30, 14, 16, 28, 20, 27, 24, 26, 29, 32, 34, 37, 39, 42, 45, 47, 50, 52, 51, 49, 48, 46, 44, 43, 41, 40, 38, 36, 35, 33, 31, 30, 28, 27, 25, 23, 21, 19, 22, 15, 8, 6, 1, 18, 1, 17, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 4, 12, 5, 11, 15, 10, 19, 21, 23, 25, 22, 18, 17, 13, 12, 11, 10]
55 [55, 53, 54, 50, 48, 52, 45, 51, 42, 40, 49, 37, 35, 47, 32, 46, 29, 27, 44, 23, 43, 20, 17, 41, 10, 11, 39, 4, 38, 8, 2, 36, 4, 2, 34, 10, 33, 11, 8, 31, 17, 30, 20, 23, 28, 27, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 53, 55, 54, 52, 51, 49, 47, 46, 44, 43, 41, 39, 38, 36, 34, 33, 31, 30, 28, 26, 24, 25, 21, 19, 16, 22, 9, 14, 6, 3, 18, 7, 5, 3, 15, 6, 9, 13, 5, 7, 12, 16, 14, 19, 21, 24, 26, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 1, 12, 1]
63 [63, 61, 62, 58, 56, 60, 53, 59, 50, 48, 57, 45, 43, 55, 40, 54, 37, 35, 52, 32, 51, 29, 27, 49, 23, 20, 47, 17, 46, 12, 9, 44, 10, 3, 42, 2, 41, 3, 2, 39, 9, 38, 12, 10, 36, 17, 20, 34, 23, 33, 27, 29, 32, 35, 37, 40, 43, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56, 58, 61, 63, 62, 60, 59, 57, 55, 54, 52, 51, 49, 47, 46, 44, 42, 41, 39, 38, 36, 34, 33, 31, 28, 30, 25, 26, 22, 19, 8, 18, 24, 11, 6, 4, 21, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 16, 5, 15, 11, 7, 13, 14, 19, 18, 22, 25, 28, 26, 31, 30, 24, 21, 16, 15, 13, 1, 14, 1]
64 [64, 62, 63, 59, 57, 61, 54, 60, 51, 49, 58, 46, 44, 56, 41, 55, 38, 36, 53, 33, 52, 29, 27, 50, 23, 20, 48, 17, 47, 12, 9, 45, 10, 3, 43, 2, 42, 3, 2, 40, 9, 39, 12, 10, 37, 17, 20, 35, 23, 34, 27, 29, 32, 33, 36, 38, 41, 44, 46, 49, 51, 54, 57, 59, 62, 64, 63, 61, 60, 58, 56, 55, 53, 52, 50, 48, 47, 45, 43, 42, 40, 39, 37, 35, 34, 32, 31, 28, 30, 25, 26, 22, 19, 8, 18, 24, 11, 6, 4, 21, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 16, 5, 15, 11, 7, 13, 14, 19, 18, 22, 25, 28, 26, 31, 30, 24, 21, 16, 15, 13, 1, 14, 1]
67 [67, 65, 66, 62, 60, 64, 57, 63, 54, 52, 61, 49, 47, 59, 44, 58, 41, 39, 56, 36, 55, 33, 30, 53, 26, 24, 51, 20, 50, 13, 11, 48, 12, 3, 46, 4, 45, 3, 7, 43, 4, 42, 11, 13, 40, 12, 7, 38, 20, 37, 24, 26, 35, 30, 34, 33, 36, 39, 41, 44, 47, 49, 52, 54, 57, 60, 62, 65, 67, 66, 64, 63, 61, 59, 58, 56, 55, 53, 51, 50, 48, 46, 45, 43, 42, 40, 38, 37, 35, 34, 32, 29, 31, 28, 25, 23, 21, 27, 18, 9, 10, 2, 5, 22, 2, 8, 6, 19, 5, 9, 17, 10, 16, 6, 8, 14, 15, 18, 21, 23, 25, 29, 28, 32, 31, 27, 22, 19, 17, 16, 14, 1, 15, 1]
72 [72, 70, 71, 67, 65, 69, 62, 68, 59, 57, 66, 54, 52, 64, 49, 63, 46, 44, 61, 41, 60, 38, 36, 58, 33, 30, 56, 27, 55, 23, 20, 53, 17, 14, 51, 10, 50, 5, 3, 48, 4, 47, 3, 5, 45, 4, 10, 43, 14, 42, 17, 20, 40, 23, 39, 27, 30, 37, 33, 36, 38, 41, 44, 46, 49, 52, 54, 57, 59, 62, 65, 67, 70, 72, 71, 69, 68, 66, 64, 63, 61, 60, 58, 56, 55, 53, 51, 50, 48, 47, 45, 43, 42, 40, 39, 37, 35, 32, 34, 31, 28, 26, 24, 22, 29, 15, 13, 8, 6, 25, 7, 12, 9, 11, 21, 6, 8, 19, 7, 18, 13, 15, 9, 16, 12, 11, 22, 24, 26, 28, 32, 31, 35, 34, 29, 25, 21, 19, 18, 2, 16, 1, 2, 1]
75 [75, 73, 74, 70, 68, 72, 65, 71, 62, 60, 69, 57, 55, 67, 52, 66, 49, 47, 64, 44, 63, 41, 39, 61, 36, 33, 59, 30, 58, 26, 24, 56, 20, 17, 54, 14, 53, 5, 6, 51, 7, 50, 3, 5, 48, 6, 3, 46, 7, 45, 14, 17, 43, 20, 42, 24, 26, 40, 30, 33, 38, 36, 39, 41, 44, 47, 49, 52, 55, 57, 60, 62, 65, 68, 70, 73, 75, 74, 72, 71, 69, 67, 66, 64, 63, 61, 59, 58, 56, 54, 53, 51, 50, 48, 46, 45, 43, 42, 40, 38, 37, 35, 32, 29, 34, 28, 25, 23, 31, 12, 15, 9, 11, 27, 21, 4, 13, 10, 8, 22, 4, 9, 12, 19, 11, 18, 15, 8, 10, 16, 13, 23, 25, 29, 28, 32, 21, 35, 37, 34, 31, 27, 22, 19, 18, 2, 16, 1, 2, 1]
76 [76, 74, 75, 71, 69, 73, 66, 72, 63, 61, 70, 58, 56, 68, 53, 67, 50, 48, 65, 45, 64, 42, 40, 62, 36, 33, 60, 30, 59, 26, 24, 57, 20, 17, 55, 14, 54, 5, 6, 52, 7, 51, 3, 5, 49, 6, 3, 47, 7, 46, 14, 17, 44, 20, 43, 24, 26, 41, 30, 33, 39, 36, 38, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56, 58, 61, 63, 66, 69, 71, 74, 76, 75, 73, 72, 70, 68, 67, 65, 64, 62, 60, 59, 57, 55, 54, 52, 51, 49, 47, 46, 44, 43, 41, 39, 38, 37, 35, 32, 29, 34, 28, 25, 23, 31, 12, 15, 9, 11, 27, 21, 4, 13, 10, 8, 22, 4, 9, 12, 19, 11, 18, 15, 8, 10, 16, 13, 23, 25, 29, 28, 32, 21, 35, 37, 34, 31, 27, 22, 19, 18, 2, 16, 1, 2, 1]
83 [83, 81, 82, 78, 76, 80, 73, 79, 70, 68, 77, 65, 63, 75, 60, 74, 57, 55, 72, 52, 71, 49, 47, 69, 44, 42, 67, 39, 66, 36, 33, 64, 30, 27, 62, 23, 61, 17, 14, 59, 15, 58, 7, 4, 56, 5, 11, 54, 4, 53, 7, 5, 51, 14, 50, 17, 15, 48, 11, 23, 46, 27, 45, 30, 33, 43, 36, 39, 42, 44, 47, 49, 52, 55, 57, 60, 63, 65, 68, 70, 73, 76, 78, 81, 83, 82, 80, 79, 77, 75, 74, 72, 71, 69, 67, 66, 64, 62, 61, 59, 58, 56, 54, 53, 51, 50, 48, 46, 45, 43, 41, 38, 40, 37, 34, 32, 29, 26, 35, 25, 16, 13, 24, 31, 8, 6, 3, 28, 12, 9, 3, 10, 6, 8, 22, 13, 21, 16, 20, 9, 19, 12, 10, 18, 26, 25, 29, 24, 32, 34, 38, 37, 41, 40, 35, 31, 28, 22, 21, 20, 19, 2, 18, 1, 2, 1]
84 [84, 82, 83, 79, 77, 81, 74, 80, 71, 69, 78, 66, 64, 76, 61, 75, 58, 56, 73, 53, 72, 50, 48, 70, 45, 43, 68, 39, 67, 36, 33, 65, 30, 27, 63, 23, 62, 17, 14, 60, 15, 59, 7, 4, 57, 5, 11, 55, 4, 54, 7, 5, 52, 14, 51, 17, 15, 49, 11, 23, 47, 27, 46, 30, 33, 44, 36, 39, 42, 43, 45, 48, 50, 53, 56, 58, 61, 64, 66, 69, 71, 74, 77, 79, 82, 84, 83, 81, 80, 78, 76, 75, 73, 72, 70, 68, 67, 65, 63, 62, 60, 59, 57, 55, 54, 52, 51, 49, 47, 46, 44, 42, 41, 38, 40, 37, 34, 32, 29, 26, 35, 25, 16, 13, 24, 31, 8, 6, 3, 28, 12, 9, 3, 10, 6, 8, 22, 13, 21, 16, 20, 9, 19, 12, 10, 18, 26, 25, 29, 24, 32, 34, 38, 37, 41, 40, 35, 31, 28, 22, 21, 20, 19, 2, 18, 1, 2, 1]
87 [87, 85, 86, 82, 80, 84, 77, 83, 74, 72, 81, 69, 67, 79, 64, 78, 61, 59, 76, 56, 75, 53, 51, 73, 48, 46, 71, 43, 70, 39, 36, 68, 33, 30, 66, 27, 65, 23, 17, 63, 14, 62, 16, 7, 60, 12, 3, 58, 4, 57, 3, 7, 55, 4, 54, 14, 17, 52, 12, 16, 50, 23, 49, 27, 30, 47, 33, 36, 45, 39, 44, 43, 46, 48, 51, 53, 56, 59, 61, 64, 67, 69, 72, 74, 77, 80, 82, 85, 87, 86, 84, 83, 81, 79, 78, 76, 75, 73, 71, 70, 68, 66, 65, 63, 62, 60, 58, 57, 55, 54, 52, 50, 49, 47, 45, 44, 42, 40, 41, 37, 35, 32, 38, 31, 28, 26, 24, 34, 8, 15, 9, 11, 6, 29, 13, 5, 10, 8, 25, 6, 9, 5, 22, 11, 21, 15, 20, 10, 13, 18, 19, 24, 26, 28, 32, 31, 35, 37, 40, 42, 41, 38, 34, 29, 25, 22, 21, 20, 18, 2, 19, 1, 2, 1]
95 [95, 93, 94, 90, 88, 92, 85, 91, 82, 80, 89, 77, 75, 87, 72, 86, 69, 67, 84, 64, 83, 61, 59, 81, 56, 54, 79, 51, 78, 48, 46, 76, 43, 40, 74, 36, 73, 33, 30, 71, 26, 70, 18, 15, 68, 17, 9, 66, 6, 65, 13, 14, 63, 4, 62, 6, 9, 60, 4, 15, 58, 18, 57, 17, 13, 55, 14, 26, 53, 30, 52, 33, 36, 50, 40, 49, 43, 46, 48, 51, 54, 56, 59, 61, 64, 67, 69, 72, 75, 77, 80, 82, 85, 88, 90, 93, 95, 94, 92, 91, 89, 87, 86, 84, 83, 81, 79, 78, 76, 74, 73, 71, 70, 68, 66, 65, 63, 62, 60, 58, 57, 55, 53, 52, 50, 49, 47, 45, 42, 39, 44, 38, 35, 32, 41, 31, 28, 34, 25, 37, 16, 12, 7, 11, 8, 3, 5, 10, 29, 3, 7, 27, 5, 8, 12, 11, 24, 16, 10, 23, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 28, 32, 31, 35, 39, 38, 42, 34, 45, 47, 44, 41, 37, 29, 27, 19, 24, 20, 23, 21, 2, 22, 1, 2, 1]
96 [96, 94, 95, 91, 89, 93, 86, 92, 83, 81, 90, 78, 76, 88, 73, 87, 70, 68, 85, 65, 84, 62, 60, 82, 57, 55, 80, 52, 79, 49, 46, 77, 43, 40, 75, 36, 74, 33, 30, 72, 26, 71, 18, 15, 69, 17, 9, 67, 6, 66, 13, 14, 64, 4, 63, 6, 9, 61, 4, 15, 59, 18, 58, 17, 13, 56, 14, 26, 54, 30, 53, 33, 36, 51, 40, 50, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 57, 60, 62, 65, 68, 70, 73, 76, 78, 81, 83, 86, 89, 91, 94, 96, 95, 93, 92, 90, 88, 87, 85, 84, 82, 80, 79, 77, 75, 74, 72, 71, 69, 67, 66, 64, 63, 61, 59, 58, 56, 54, 53, 51, 50, 48, 47, 45, 42, 39, 44, 38, 35, 32, 41, 31, 28, 34, 25, 37, 16, 12, 7, 11, 8, 3, 5, 10, 29, 3, 7, 27, 5, 8, 12, 11, 24, 16, 10, 23, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 28, 32, 31, 35, 39, 38, 42, 34, 45, 47, 44, 41, 37, 29, 27, 19, 24, 20, 23, 21, 2, 22, 1, 2, 1]
```

For instructional purposes, here's the source code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LangfordPairing {
    static void langford(int N) {
        BitSet bs = new BitSet();
        bs.set(N * 2);
        put(bs, N, new int[2 * N]);
    }
    static void put(BitSet bs, int n, int[] arr) {
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            System.exit(0); // one is enough!
        }
        for (int i = -1, L = bs.length() - n - 1;
                    (i = bs.nextClearBit(i + 1)) < L ;) {

            final int j = i + n + 1;
            if (!bs.get(j)) {
                arr[i] = n;
                arr[j] = n;
                bs.flip(i);
                bs.flip(j);
                put(bs, n - 1, arr);
                bs.flip(i);
                bs.flip(j);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        langford(87);
    }
}
```

Solutions for some `N` values are missing; they are known to require an abnormally large number of operations just to find the first solution by brute force.

Note that as mentioned, there are generally many solutions for any given `N`. For `N = 7`, there are 26 solutions:

```
[7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 1]
[7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1]
[7, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 1, 5, 1]
[7, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5]
[7, 1, 4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2]
[7, 1, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 2, 5]
[7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2]
[7, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 1, 6, 1]

[5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 4, 1]
[3, 7, 4, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5, 1]
[5, 7, 4, 1, 6, 1, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2]
[5, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 6, 1, 4]
[1, 7, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 3, 5]
[5, 7, 1, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2]
[1, 7, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4]
[2, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 1, 6]

[6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 7, 1, 5, 1]
[2, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 4, 3]
[3, 6, 7, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 5]
[5, 1, 7, 1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 7, 6, 4, 3]
[2, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 4, 1, 7, 6, 5, 4]
[4, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 7, 6, 3, 5]
[5, 2, 7, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4]
[3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 6, 1]
[3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4]
[2, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 3, 1, 7, 1, 6, 5]
```

#### Related links

- [John Miller - Langford's Problem - Oddity for some `N` values](http://legacy.lclark.edu/%7Emiller/langford/langford-ops.html)
- [OEIS A014552 - Number of solutions to Langford problem](http://oeis.org/classic/A014552)

#### Attachments

- [Source code and output on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/efyQU)

Comment: Great research. It always seems Knuth has written about *everything*.

Answer (score 2):

I adopted an elimination approach with paper and pencil for L(2,7).

1. Place the two 7s. Just three possibilities
2. Place the two 6s and so on.
3. It is obvious when placing the 1s, 2s, and 3s simultaneously whether there is a solution or not.
4. I found 18 of the 26 solutions thus.
5. When time and paper permits I will tackle L(2,8).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've seen this in Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming".  I'll look it up when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good heuristic would be to start with the biggest numbers. You'll still need backtracking though.

The problem with the problem is that having a solution for n-1 usually doesn't help you much to find a solution for n.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always possible? I can see the pattern is probable and not definite. It doesn't work for 1s or 1s and 2s.

If it is probablistic, the best idea would be to start with brute force and keep on eliminating wrong options as an when you encounter them.